# how to call api in angular 10

Tags: node.js, api, aws-api-gateway, angular10

I am writing an Angular website and I am trying to post some payload to an API which is built on AWS cloud.

I wrote my code as below:

```
  async doCognitoLogin(email, password) {
    const payloads = {
      poolData: {
        UserPoolId: 'us-east-2',
        ClientId: '324234234234sad',
        Paranoia: '7',
      },
      params: {
        username: 'myemail@yahoo.com',
        password: '213123',
      },
    };

    const url =
      'https://fakeurl234.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/Prod/signin';
    let response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
        mode: 'no-cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
        cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
        credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
        redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
        referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer', // no-referrer, *no-referrer-when-downgrade, origin, origin-when-cross-origin, same-origin, strict-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin, unsafe-url
        body: JSON.stringify(payloads), // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
      });

    if (response.ok) {
      // if HTTP-status is 200-299
      // get the response body (the method explained below)
      let json = await response.json();
    } else {
      alert('HTTP-Error: ' + response.status);
    }
)
```

I monitor my API input and output in cloud watch and I am receiving the request from my site(localhost) and I am logging the response from my API also but my code don't receive the output and I am just getting exception of

> HTTP-Error: 0

I tested did I config cors by using this website (http://test-cors.org/) and the result is correct:

```
Sending POST request to https://fakesite1234.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/Prod/signin

Fired XHR event: loadstart
Fired XHR event: readystatechange
Fired XHR event: readystatechange
Fired XHR event: progress
Fired XHR event: readystatechange
Fired XHR event: load

XHR status: 200
XHR status text:
XHR exposed response headers:
content-length: 3877
content-type: application/json
```

My API is working fine with POSTMAN, but it is not working fine with my code. would you mind help me to find the reason and help me to resolve it, please?

Answer (score 0):

Angular provides `HttpClient` to make requests, please refer to https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request

Comment: I tried this way first, but I think due to CORS it is not allowing me to test my code locally. do you have any example with HttpClient for this purpose?

Comment: If you are encountering an error with cors you should solve it on your server, you cannot disable cors on your browser  using Javascript ( Postman does not check server cors policy so even if your server is not allowing CORS, you will get a result on Postman). if your server is a Nodejs Express you can enable cross by adding this middleware
app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
  next();
})

Comment: so you are telling that I shouldn't put mode: 'no-cors'? I am using angular to run the server and my site is also uploaded into S3 as a static site. I am not using node server I assume. can you elbrate more where I can add the above code?